# populating json data inside Googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a lot of research on this topic but couldn't find an appropriate solution.
I simply have an api which include school name and its latitude,longitude.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Little Angels Higher Secondary School",
      "latitude":27.6514,
      "longitude":85.3359
   },
   {  
      "id":6,
      "name":"Baltimore Secondary School",
      "latitude":27.6514,
      "longitude":85.3359
   }
]
```

I parsed this api data.Using GPStracker class I successfully included a marker on google map at my current location.Now I want to add a marker to all the school location in that google map so that I can know the nearest school to me once I open the google map.This is all what I did how ever it shows null pointer exception.

```
   package com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.R;

import com.example.user.educationhunt.SchoolDetails;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.adapter.CustomListAdapter;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.AppController;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.FeeClass;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.GpsLocation;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.MySchool;
import com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.OurSchool;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NearMe extends Fragment {
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    GpsLocation gpsLocation;
    double longitude, latitude;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private RadioButton radioSexButton;
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    MySchool mySchool;
    Marker place;
    LatLng  current_location ;

    private static final String TAG = NearMe.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String url = "http://www.myeducationhunt.com/api/v1/schools";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_me, container, false);

        radioSexButton = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioSchool);

        if (isConnected()) {
            mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mMapView.onResume();

            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            gpsLocation = new GpsLocation(getContext());


            if (gpsLocation.canGetLocation()) {
                longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "latitude:" + latitude + "Longitude:" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading…");
            pDialog.show();


            JsonArrayRequest schoolRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    mySchool = new MySchool();

                                    mySchool.setId(""+obj.getInt("id"));
                                    mySchool.setName(""+obj.getString("name"));
                                    mySchool.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(""+obj.getDouble("latitude")));
                                    mySchool.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(""+obj.getDouble("longitude")));


                                    al.add(mySchool);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(schoolRequest);


            mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                    googleMap = mMap;

                    LatLng schoollatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(schoollatlng).title("MyLocation"));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(schoollatlng).zoom(10).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(mySchool.getLatitude(), mySchool.getLongitude());
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(mySchool.getName()));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition1 = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latlng).zoom(10).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition1));
                }
            });

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return v;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any one to help me?Please Help.Thanks in advance

This is MySchool class

```
package com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos;

/**
 * Created by user on 12/28/2016.
 */
public class MySchool {

    String id;
    String name;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

This is my error log

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.user.educationhunt, PID: 20472
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.example.user.educationhunt.pojos.MySchool.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.user.educationhunt.fragment.NearMe$3.onMapReady(NearMe.java:159)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                                    at zu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                                                                                    at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
12-28 10:06:05.046 20472-21276/com.example.user.educationhunt I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 81
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your school marker should run after google complete initialized. Below are the code sample.

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                LatLng schoollatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(schoollatlng).title("MyLocation"));
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(schoollatlng).zoom(10).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                drawSchoolMarker();
            }
});
```

Create new method in the class

```
private void drawSchoolMarker(){

    JsonArrayRequest schoolRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                MySchool school = new MySchool();

                                school.setId(""+obj.getInt("id"));
                                school.setName(""+obj.getString("name"));
                                school.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(""+obj.getDouble("latitude")));
                                school.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(""+obj.getDouble("longitude")));


                                al.add(school);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        //iterate from arraylist
                        for(MySchool school : al){
                           LatLng latlng = new LatLng(school.getLatitude(), school.getLongitude());
                           googleMap.addMarker(new  MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(school.getName()));
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(schoolRequest);
}
```

I didn't test the code but it should work.

Comment: Iterate the arraylist of school instead to draw all the school marker.

Comment: Your above code just gives the last school location.Bro I am a novice,It would be great if you would tell me how to iterate so that I could get all the schools location.Thanks alot and I apologize for this stupid request

Comment: I am editing the answer with arraylist iteration. Perhaps, I should not edit the answers with the hope that you learn the basic and not 100% depends on the answers code. However I also feel the same when jumped to programming fews years ago.

Comment: I am getting error at this line  for(MySchool school : al).Error says required Object found MySchool

Comment: Yes you will get the error because the way you declare the arraylist. It should be `List<MySchool> al = new ArrayList<MySchool>();`

Answer (score 1):

After reading all school locations do some thing like by using your Array List

```
Marker  place;
LatLng  current_location ;
    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
        current_location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(al.get(i).getLatitude()),Double.parseDouble(al.get(i).getLongitude()));
        place= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current_location).title("school name here"));
    }
```

Comment: Bro I am having error in getLatitude() and getLongitude() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should get NullPointerException in the line:

```
 LatLng latlng = new LatLng(ourSchool.latitude, ourSchool.longitude);
```

because ourSchool is pointing to Null. You have added all the ourSchool objects in the  ArrayList "al"  like : `al.add(ourSchool)`

now try to iterate from the ArrayList "al" after adding the data in the ArrayList.

Also your below code is running before the getting response from the url and your "ourSchool" not initialise till that time.

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                    googleMap = mMap;

                    LatLng schoollatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(schoollatlng).title("MyLocation"));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(schoollatlng).zoom(10).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(ourSchool.latitude, ourSchool.longitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(ourSchool.schoolName));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition1 = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latlng).zoom(10).build();
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition1));
                }
            });
```

OurSchool class:

```
class OurSchool{

String id;
String name;
double latitude;
double longitude;


public void setId(String id){
this.id=id;
}

public String getId(){
return id;
}
public void setName(String name){
this.name=name;
}

public String getName(){
return name;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude){
this.latitute=latitude;
}

public double getLatitude(){
return latitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude){
this.longitude=longitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
return longitude;
}


}
```

then set value in OurSchool class object like:

```
 ourSchool.setId(""+obj.getInt("id"));
```

in place of

```
ourSchool.schoolId = obj.getInt("id");
```

same way set values for other also

Comment: Bro I aspect solution here,not to figure out my problem.I am aware of my problem

Comment: Hi therameshbista, I mentioned solution also in my line :

"now try to iterate from the ArrayList "al" after adding the data in the ArrayList."

and "Manikanta" have written code for the same so I did not write code for this.

Comment: Dear Arun kumar sir, I have updated my question code with suggestions from yours.However I am getting error in getlatitude() and getlongitude(); method at this line.Please have a look and help to fix my error                                             current_location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(al.get(i).getLatitude()),Double.parseDouble(al.get(i).getLongitude()))

Comment: Cannot resolve method getlatitude(); and getlongitude(); with red text.plzzz help

Comment: Your class "OurSchool" should have these methods otherwise it will throw compile time errors.

Comment: I am editing my answer with code of OurSchool class.

Comment: Sure sir i hope you will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131593/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-therameshbista).